# how to resize or reposition controls based on screen resolutions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, resize, resolution

I making a Windows application with VS2010. Where i'm using panels to fight with different screen resolutions. 
For some of my controls I used anchor property set to top,bottom without docking them to parent panel. when i run this program on the machine which is used to develop, result was as expected,But when i tried this one on different resolution its results were worse than expected. Some controls are partially displayed.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802015/controls-resize-based-on-screen-resolution) to this by re-sizing my controls based on screen resolutions. But that didn't worked for me as controls were re-sized but they were out of display area.

I couldn't relocate them based on resolution.

how would i set their position based on resolution.

or

i should assume  minimum screen resolution (lets say 800*600) and program with this resolution.

Plz help!

Comment: you could try using a TableLayoutPanel to better fit and control the layout, but a minimum screen size or even form size is not unreasonable.

Comment: thanks Plutonix. have one more question.. if i use tablelayoutpanel then will it affect other components when i add other control to form dynamically?

Comment: you'll have to either leave space in the TLP or nest one inside the other to reserve room for added controls.  you might also see if a FlowLayoutPanel inside a TLP does what you want for added controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the solution was to use TableLayoutPanel and panels to do this. 
I was bit right, but this doesn't work in all the cases.

Found a solution [here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802015/....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802015/controls-resize-based-on-screen-resolution)

Cheers..!